# getting django.apps from shell but not script

Tags: python, django, bash, shell, django-settings

I can get my apps info in the shell:

```
In [1]: from django.apps import apps

In [2]: info = apps.all_models      

In [3]: for item in info:           
    print(item)
   ...:     
mailer
auth
analytics
subscribe
staticfiles
contenttypes
layout
contact
```

but not within a script. the script is in the main site folder, ie with `manage.py`, whereas the settings file is in `mysite/project/settings.py`. The script is just in `mysite`, above the project folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re, ast
# This should be the directory that contains the directory containing settings.py
# sys.path.add('/path/to/mysite') 
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

HOMEPATH = os.path.expanduser("~")

PROJECT_PATH = "{}/work_projects/mysite".format(HOMEPATH)

ENTRY_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "project")

MOMMY_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "model_mommy")

MOMMY_TESTPATH = os.path.join(MOMMY_PATH, "tests")

sys.path.append(ENTRY_PATH) 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.project.settings")

from django.apps import apps

info = apps.all_models

for item in info:           
    print(item)
```

there is no output, info is blank. Importing `django.conf.settings` and playing with the settings does work. Why doesn't doing the same thing work in this script? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing this (I think mysite should not be in settings line):

```
import os, sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
import django
django.setup()

for item in django.apps.all_models:
    print(item)
```